# Why do I get this error when I open RStudio "Error in python_config_impl(python)"?

Tags: python-3.x, rstudio

I am getting this error when starting up **RStudio**.

```
Error in python_config_impl(python) : 
Error 1 occurred running /usr/bin/python3:
```

I have tried reinstalling **RStudio** but the same error appears, and I don't know how to fix it.

I haven't installed **Python** so I don't know why this is appearing.